# Time is not properly synchronised with Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, time

I select the option **Automatically from the Internet** in Ubuntu. But the time is not the real time as it should be. I am attaching a screen shot. Could anyone give me a solution for that. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

install ntp server:  `sudo apt-get install ntp`

and run `sudo ntpdate ntp.ubuntu.com`

Sources---> [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214246/how-to-fix-wrong-system-time-and-date) and [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/56167/clock-displays-incorrect-time)

Answer (score 1):

You could run the following command to update the system time:

```
sudo ntpd -a -b
```

Run the following command to verify the same:

```
sudo ntpq -p
```

Then, run the following to update the clock:

```
sudo ntpd -gq
```

Also, you may need to install ntp. You can do it by executing the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Delay and offset should not be all zeros. If so, run the first two commands again.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and type "sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata" then configure the timezone from the popup that will appear, select the correct zone and it should and check the time using the "time" command. The sudo command will want a password so your user account should have elevated rights, i.e. be in sudo group.